# How to embed YouTube video using object tag?

Tags: html, url, youtube, html-object

I am trying to include YouTube video by `object` tag in HTML:

```
<object width="500" height="500" data="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqsL0QQaSP4"></object>
```

Currently, the video doesn't display. I searched on W3Schools, they have similar code with a different URL and it works:

```
<object width="420" height="315"
data="https://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</object>
```

What kind of URL can I use for the `object` `data` attribute?

Comment: Bad idea, use an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to add a "v/" to the end of youtube.com. Basically, the new video link that you embed is https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=aqsL0QQaSP4

```html
<object width="420" height="315"
data="https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=aqsL0QQaSP4">
</object>
```

Comment: yeah it worked. But my question is what kind of url we can put into object data attribute.

Comment: I believe you will need to use a direct link, like the youtube.com/v/ one. Think of it like this; The youtube.com/watch link would be equivalent to imgur.com/gallery/abc123, while the /v/ link would be like imgur.com/abc123.png. You wouldn't use a website link in an <img> tag, you would use a direct link. This is the YouTube equivalent. Anyways, if my answer helped you out, could you please accept it so other people know where to look?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube's recommended way of embedding videos is using iframe. This is what it would look like:

```html
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aqsL0QQaSP4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**EDIT:** If you wish to use the `<object>` tag, check out my other answer.